# how to use await and async with richtextbox?

Tags: c#, async-await

i tried to make a app to check ebay current watchers. i use following code find ebay watcher count.. it woks fine. then i use await asyncro code to fix UI blocking..

but it is getting invalidoperationexception was unhandled exception.

```
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task<int> task = new Task<int>(counting);
        task.Start();

        label1.Text = "Please wait";
        await task;

    }

  private int counting()
    {

        string[] idlist = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n'); // <= getting exception

        // foreach (string id in idlist)
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(idlist.Length); i++)
        {
            string url = "http://m.ebay.com/itm/" + idlist[i];
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            // richTextBox2.Text += sr.ReadToEnd();
            string a = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();




            string number = String.Empty;
            string pattern = @"(?<=""defaultWatchCount""\s*:\s*)\d+";
            string input = a;

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
            {
                number = m.Value;

            }
            richTextBox2.Text += number + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

I don't have much knowledge about await and async... could anyone plz fix this error?

Comment: You are crossing threads and also you should try to avoid creating `new Task`s manually. Use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Take the string from the control when in the button click event handler and pass it to the function. The web calls can be placed on a background thread(s) and once completed updating the control back on the UI thread withing the button click handler.

Comment: where should i add `Task.Run` in the code?

Comment: within `Task counting(string text_from_richTextBox1)` or just wrap the function from within the event handler

Comment: should i change `int` to `string` in the function? or `Task<int> task = new Task<int>(counting(string text_from_richTextBox1));`

Comment: could you explain it via **Answer**

Comment: `Task task = await Task.Run(() => counting(text_from_richTextBox1))`

Comment: Heading off to a meeting now so wont have time till later to tackle this.

Comment: anyone plz help

Comment: Eventually got a chance to take a look at it. Review the provided answer. It should be enough to get you started. Also take some time and read up more on [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access UI controls from a thread different to the one that created it will cause cross thread access violations. So if the goal is to make the web calls on a background thread then you need to separate the background tasks from the UI

The following is a refactor of the original code that takes a collection of ids and using `HttpClient` to make asynchronous web calls. All the web calls will be done in parallel on separate threads.

```
static Lazy<HttpClient> client = new Lazy<HttpClient>(() => {
    string baseUrl = "http://m.ebay.com/itm/";
    var client = new HttpClient() {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl)
    };
    return client;
});

private Task<string[]> GetWatchCountsAsync(string[] idlist) {
    string pattern = @"(?<=""defaultWatchCount""\s*:\s*)\d+";
    var tasks = idlist.Select(async id => {
        var input = await client.Value.GetStringAsync(id.Trim());
        string number = String.Empty;
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern)) {
            number += m.Value;
        }
        return number;
    });
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

So now in the button click handler you start in the UI thread, offload the requests to other threads and wait for them to complete while not locking the UI thread. Once complete you extract the returned values and pass them on as needed

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    label1.Text = "Please wait..."; //UI Thread
    var idlist = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n'); //UI Thread
    var numbers = await GetWatchCountsAsync(idlist); //background thread(s) (non-blocking)
    richTextBox2.Text += string.Join(Environment.NewLine, numbers); // Back on UI thread
    label1.Text = "Done"; //UI Thread
}
```